# How do I write a function that can compose `FnMut` closures?

Tags: closures, rust

Here's a `compose` function that can compose `Fn` closures:

```
fn compose<'a, T1, T2, T3, F1, F2>(f: F1, g: F2) -> Box<Fn(T1) -> T3 + 'a>
    where F1: Fn(T1) -> T2 + 'a,
          F2: Fn(T2) -> T3 + 'a
{
    box move |x| g(f(x))
}
```

How do I make it so that this compose function can take `FnMut` closures? I tried:

```
fn compose<'a, T1, T2, T3, F1, F2>(f: F1, g: F2) -> Box<FnMut(T1) -> T3 + 'a>
    where F1: FnMut(T1) -> T2 + 'a,
          F2: FnMut(T2) -> T3 + 'a
{
    box move |x| g(f(x))
}
```

But it complains about:

```
error: cannot borrow captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure as mutable
         box move |x| g(f(x))
                      ^
error: cannot borrow captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure as mutable
         box move |x| g(f(x))
                        ^
```

Extending this, can it be made to work with `FnOnce` closures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local variables `f` and `g` must be mutable:

```
fn compose<'a, T1, T2, T3, F1, F2>(mut f: F1, mut g: F2) -> Box<FnMut(T1) -> T3 + 'a>
    where F1: FnMut(T1) -> T2 + 'a,
          F2: FnMut(T2) -> T3 + 'a
{
    Box::new(move |x| g(f(x)))
}
```

Comment: Interesting. The error message is not very useful here, I wonder if that can be improved.