# How to implement the pipe / compose function?

Tags: rust, function-composition

I'm trying to write a 'pipe' function, which is pretty straightforward in Javascript:

```
const pipe = (...funcs) => val => (
  funcs.reduce((acc, func) => func(acc), val)
)
```

Example usage:

```
const sqrt = v => Math.sqrt(v);
const half = v => v / 2;
const plusFive = v => v + 5;

plusFive(half(sqrt(16))); // 7

const doStuff = pipe(sqrt, half, plusFive);
doStuff(16); // 7
```

How to do same thing in Rust? Thanks!

Comment: For some reason I can't seem to be able to add the right tag, `piping`; the UNIX-related `pipe` is inserted instead :/.

Comment: Rust does not have functions that take an arbitrary number of arguments. You can implement this as a macro or accept some syntactic overhead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786955/how-to-compose-functions-in-rust for the 2-argument version.

Comment: @SebastianRedl your link also provides the macro version for compose, so exactly what the OP asks

Comment: @hellow So it does, didn't even notice.

Comment: Since I've written it already, [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=922f122728f05097ccd9738183ec4b48&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) is an example for the three function case. But yes, the linked answer contains the general solution.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Sorry for duplication :(

Comment: @streletss Don't worry! Duplicate questions are not necessarily a bad thing. It's really helpful to have multiple versions of the same question (with different formulations). That way, people can more easily find the answer.