# How to compose two async function in Rust

Tags: asynchronous, rust, functional-programming

I am trying to write a higher order function that compose two async function.

i am basically looking for the async version [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45792463/50653)

```
fn compose<A, B, C, G, F>(f: F, g: G) -> impl Fn(A) -> C
where
    F: Fn(A) -> B,
    G: Fn(B) -> C,
{
    move |x| g(f(x))
}
```

This my attempt so far.

```
fn compose_future<A, B, C, G, F>(f: F, g: G) -> (impl Fn(A) -> impl Future<C>)
where
    F: Fn(A) -> impl Future<B>,
    G: Fn(B) -> impl Future<C>,
{
    move |x| async { g(f(x).await).await }
}
```

and i get the following error

```
error[E0562]: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types
  --> src\channel.rs:13:17
   |
13 |     F: Fn(A) -> impl Future<B>,
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is it possible to accomplish this ?

Comment: Your function's name is `compose_future` but what you are trying to do is composing future generators, Do you wan to compose futures or generators? If you want to compose futures there is pretty good combinators in futures-rs, I would just it. For the other case you may create this kind of a structure; please check: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ac8973c719e172d21fc16e83db5e6c6f This structure simply gives you an access to future generator, and after calling it, it simply generates the combined future, it is roughly the same behavior that  you require.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is possible to do it that simple with `impl Trait`-s. The one solution I can come up with is old-fashioned future types usage without async-await feature. TLDR: [full playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ef8df77eb8eb0843858b145a5216ad4f). Async-await uses a generators which internally holds a state machine, so we need to define it manually:

```rust
enum State<In, F, FutOutF, G, FutOutG> {
    Initial(In, F, G), // Out composed type created
    FirstAwait(FutOutF, G), // Composed type waits for the first future
    SecondAwait(FutOutG), // and for the second
    // here can be a `Completed` state, but it simpler
    // to handle it with `Option<..>` in our future itself
}
```

Then define a composed type itself:

```rust
struct Compose<In, Out, F, FutOutF, G, FutOutG> {
    state: Option<State<In, F, FutOutF, G, FutOutG>>,
    _t: PhantomData<Out>,
}

// And "entry-point" would be something like that:
fn compose_fut<In, Out, F, FutOutF, G, FutOutG>(
    i: In,
    f: F,
    g: G,
) -> Compose<In, Out, F, FutOutF, G, FutOutG> {
    Compose {
        state: Some(State::Initial(i, f, g)),
        _t: PhantomData,
    }
}
```

Then comes the most complex part - `impl Future` itself, here a base impl declaration without implementation:

```rust
impl<In, Mid, Out, F, FutOutF, G, FutOutG> Future for Compose<In, Out, F, FutOutF, G, FutOutG>
where
    FutOutF: Future<Output = Mid>,
    F: FnOnce(In) -> FutOutF,
    FutOutG: Future<Output = Out>,
    G: FnOnce(Mid) -> FutOutG,
{
    type Output = Out;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        // here comes the magic
    }
}
```

Values transformed as following: `In -> Mid -> Out`, where `F` and `G` are our composed functions and their output are `FutOutF` and `FutOutG` accordingly. And finally `Future::poll` implementation:

```rust
let this = unsafe { self.get_unchecked_mut() };

let state = this.state.take();

match state {
    None => Poll::Pending, // invalid state
    Some(State::Initial(i, f, g)) => {
        let fut = f(i);
        this.state = Some(State::FirstAwait(fut, g));
        cx.waker().wake_by_ref();
        Poll::Pending
    }
    Some(State::FirstAwait(mut fut, g)) => {
        let val = match unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(&mut fut) }.poll(cx) {
            Poll::Ready(v) => v,
            Poll::Pending => {
                this.state = Some(State::FirstAwait(fut, g));
                return Poll::Pending;
            }
        };
        let fut = g(val);
        this.state = Some(State::SecondAwait(fut));
        cx.waker().wake_by_ref();
        Poll::Pending
    }
    Some(State::SecondAwait(mut fut)) => {
        match unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(&mut fut) }.poll(cx) {
            Poll::Ready(v) => Poll::Ready(v),
            Poll::Pending => {
                this.state = Some(State::SecondAwait(fut));
                Poll::Pending
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I avoid any library to make it "plain", usually unsafe parts are handled with `pin-project` or `futures::pin_mut`. The state management is fairly complex, so I suggest to re-check the implementation, there might be mistakes.