# Higher order functions supporting possible lifetimes

Tags: rust

Suppose I have a higher order function, such as [composition from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45792463):

```
fn compose<A, B, C, G, F>(f: F, g: G) -> impl Fn(A) -> C
where
    F: Fn(A) -> B,
    G: Fn(B) -> C,
{
    move |x| g(f(x))
}
```

and I want to partially apply it, as in

```
fn id<T>(x: &T) -> &T { x }

fn compose_with_id<T, U, F>(f: F) -> impl Fn(&T) -> U
where
    F: Fn(&T) -> U
{
    compose(id, f)
}
```

This doesn't compile. IIUC the issue is that at the `compose` callsite, we must substitute a specific type for `A` (including a specific lifetime), but the return value needs to implement `Fn(&'a T) -> U` for all `'a`. I tried moving the call to `compose` into a closure:

```
fn compose_with_id<T, U, F>(f: F) -> impl Fn(&T) -> U
where
    F: Fn(&T) -> U
{
    move |t| compose(id, f)(t)
}
```

This also doesn't compile. The problem is now that `compose` is trying to take ownership of `f` each time the resulting function is called. I don't see a way to fix `compose_with_id` (without insisting `F: Copy`); `compose` takes ownership of `f`, which can only happen once, so we must choose one lifetime, but the return value needs to handle any lifetime.

We could create a variant of `compose` that works for references:

```
fn compose<A, B, C, G, F>(f: F, g: G) -> impl Fn(&A) -> C
where
    F: Fn(&A) -> &B,
    G: Fn(&B) -> C,
{
    move |x| g(f(x))
}
```

(whose return value has a HRTB) but it can't be used for non-reference inputs.

How can I define `compose` such that it can be partially applied to non-copyable functions with or without reference inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about add lifetime annotations to compose_with_id?

```
fn compose_with_id<'a, T, U, F>(f: F) -> impl Fn(&'a T) -> U
where
    T: 'a,
    U: 'a,
    F: Fn(&'a T) -> U,
{
    compose(id, f)
}
```

Comment: This makes the return type of compose_with_ids narrower (namely `Fn(&'a T) -> U` for some specific `'a`, rather than `for<'a> Fn(&'a T) -> U`), but maybe that's the best we can do.