# Function composition chain in Rust

Tags: rust, functional-programming, function-composition

I want to implement **function composition** in an object method chain in Rust.

Before that, I confirmed that implementation of an object method chain for "pipe" of **function application** is possible in Rust as follows:

https://docs.rs/apply/0.2.2/apply/trait.Apply.html

```
trait Pipe: Sized {
    fn pipe<F, B>(self, f: F) -> B
    where
        F: FnOnce(Self) -> B,
    {
        f(self)
    }
}

impl<T> Pipe for T {}
 
fn main() {
    let string = 1.pipe(|x| x * 2).pipe(|x| x + 1).pipe(|x| x.to_string());

    println!("{}", string);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d6210a499e2522ff04e0cbbeef8cedc5

---

Now, the code of function composition is
[How to compose functions in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786955/how-to-compose-functions-in-rust)

```
fn compose<A, B, C, G, F>(f: F, g: G) -> impl Fn(A) -> C
where
    F: Fn(A) -> B,
    G: Fn(B) -> C,
{
    move |x| g(f(x))
}

fn main() {
    let multiply_and_add = compose(|x| x * 2, |x| x + 2);
    let divide_and_subtract = compose(|x| x / 2, |x| x - 2);

    let finally = compose(multiply_and_add, divide_and_subtract);
    println!("Result is {}", finally(10));
}
```

---

So the goal would be

```
let composed_f = (|x| x * 2).compose(|x| x + 1).compose(|x| x.to_string());
```

and what is the proper code to implement **function composition** in an object method chain in Rust like "pipe"?

---

EDIT

for function composition macro quoted from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45792463/11316608

```
macro_rules! compose {
    ( $last:expr ) => { $last };
    ( $head:expr, $($tail:expr), +) => {
        compose_two($head, compose!($($tail),+))
    };
}

fn compose_two<A, B, C, G, F>(f: F, g: G) -> impl Fn(A) -> C
where
    F: Fn(A) -> B,
    G: Fn(B) -> C,
{
    move |x| g(f(x))
}

fn main() {
    let add = |x| x + 2;
    let multiply = |x| x * 2;
    let divide = |x| x / 2;
    let intermediate = compose!(add, multiply, divide);

    let subtract = |x| x - 2;
    let finally = compose!(intermediate, subtract);

    println!("Result is {}", finally(10));
}
```

Comment: Side note: you should take `FnMut` when possible. There's no reason to restrict callers to `FnOnce`.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks for your side-note. It looks true and I only takes the first method from the example trait: https://docs.rs/apply/0.2.2/src/apply/lib.rs.html#8-23

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing this directly on closures is tricky, but we can make it vastly simpler with a newtype that represents a composeable function.  This adds a step to convert into a composeable function and then out again at the end, but it winds up being pretty reasonable (especially considering its expressive power), it requires no boxing or other clever tricks, and the implementation is very easy to understand.

Because it winds up with unboxed, nested closure invocations, it is also very likely that the compiler will be able to optimize away all of the composition calls and inline the closures into each other, likely even into the final call site.

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct ComposeableFn<F, A, B>(F, PhantomData<*mut A>, PhantomData<*mut B>);

impl<F, A, B> ComposeableFn<F, A, B>
    where F: FnMut(A) -> B
{
    pub fn new(f: F) -> Self {
        Self(f, Default::default(), Default::default())
    }
    
    pub fn compose<C>(self, mut next: impl FnMut(B) -> C)
        -> ComposeableFn<impl FnMut(A) -> C, A, C>
    {
        let mut prior = self.0;
        
        ComposeableFn::new(move |v| next(prior(v)))
    }
    
    pub fn into_inner(self) -> F {
        self.0
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```
fn main() {
    let mut composed_f = ComposeableFn::new(|x: i32| x * 2)
        .compose(|x| x + 1)
        .compose(|x| x.to_string())
        .into_inner();
        
    println!("{:?}", composed_f(21)); // "43"
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1deb117582da24f1acd1b5174152e771))

---

The `PhantomData` members are required to allow the implementation to name `A` and `B`, otherwise they would be considered unused.  I chose `*mut _` as this makes the type invariant in `A` and `B`.

---

You can make the expression of a composition a bit nicer with a macro:

```
macro_rules! compose {
    ({ $fh:expr } $( { $ft:expr } )*) => {
        ComposeableFn::new($fh)
        $( .compose($ft) )*
        .into_inner()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut composed_f = compose!(
        {|x: i32| x * 2}
        {|x| x + 1}
        {|x| x.to_string()}
    );
        
    println!("{:?}", composed_f(21));
}
```

Comment: This is like one of "wow" because your implementation is well-considered for simplicity (that I also consider it most) among other possibilities of implementations that I need to learn all of them that I don't know anyway. Thank you! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @SmoothTraderKen I'm glad you find it useful! Note that I didn't extensively test with closures that borrow -- you may need to tweak `compose` to introduce a named lifetime parameter to handle cases where closures borrow from their environment. I didn't run into any such issues, but I'm not confident enough to say they won't come up.

Comment: Thanks again for your side-note, @cdhowie. I have an impression that the example-code of `trait Pipe` of **function application** may be refined by using your code somehow, but I don't know so far. If there's something let me mention to you here. I appreciate it again.

Comment: @SmoothTraderKen The roadblock there is that you'd need your trait's `compose` function to return `impl FnMut(A) -> C` but trait functions can't (currently) have `impl` return types, and associated types won't work either since closure types can't be named. RFC 2071 might help here but it's not stable yet. You can work around this by boxing the closure, but then you're adding indirection and heap allocation per composed function, and severely limiting the optimizer's ability to inline the composed functions.

Comment: All of that to say, the newtype approach works today and should have pretty darn close to zero runtime impact compared to composing the functions by hand, doesn't depend on unstable features, and the two bookends of create-newtype and unwrap-newtype are, in my opinion, both trivial and easily understood. And, on second thought, you can probably hide that all in a macro anyway.

Comment: Oh RFC 2071=existential types. Sounds like you are well experienced functional programmer. Then let me ask, please.  Would you also choose the two bookends' new type approach for function application(apply/pipe)?

Comment: @SmoothTraderKen Honestly, for both, a macro might wind up being simpler overall, as well as be easier to reason about and have fewer surprises.

Comment: Thanks for your whole comments and answer.  I understood and I will study this approach&syntax further and deeper. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @SmoothTraderKen No problem. By the way, [here is an example of a `fnpipe!` macro](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3b96d8b0d152ad46ebf8a88e340a5eaf). It could probably be improved, this is just a first stab at it. In particular, type inference has some trouble figuring it out.

Comment: @SmoothTraderKen Added an example of how to build a macro on top of the type in my answer. This makes the syntax a bit nicer.

Comment: Thanks again! Looking at the macro, in the end, the code in another QA looks more concise. Please see my EDIT on my Q and let me hear your thought. Is the functionality of the function-composition same?

Comment: The fundamental reason to chose `object.method()` style that I prefer here is I think it's similar to binary operations such as `f1 . f2` .  The multi arguments function style such as `compose(f1,f2)` has a problem of Nested Parentheses that I would like to avoid.

Comment: @SmoothTraderKen The macro allows you to specify as many functions as you want in one invocation, though. There isn't any nesting. The macro you've posted and the macro I posted work in almost exactly the same way.

Comment: Hi, I was thinking to ask you more here, but on second thought, I thought it's better to start new quesion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72840909/function-composition-chain-with-a-pure-macro-in-rust  If you have time, please give me your thought. Thanks again!!