# Function composition chain with a pure macro in Rust

Tags: rust, macros, function-composition

I've read

[How to compose functions in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786955/how-to-compose-functions-in-rust)

[Function composition chain in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72597835/function-composition-chain-in-rust)

I've learned implementing a Function composition chain in Rust is rather difficult, and people use Macro with some function, however, I wonder if it's possible to use only a macro without a `compose` function from the first place.

I mean

`compose!(f, g)` can be simply reritten to `|x| g(f(x))` (just another syntax)

or

`compose!(f, g, h)` can be similarly rewitten to `|x| h(g(f(x)))`

`compose!(f, g, h, i)` can be similarly rewitten to `|x| i(h(g(f(x))))`

`compose!(f, g, h, i,...)` can be similarly rewitten to `|x| ...(i(h(g(f(x)))))`

as the recursive manner.

I guess this recursive macro does not need the actual function composition function.
I've just started learning Rust macro, so what would be the smart way to code this?

PS. Does the type-inference work fine with macro in Rust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that only using macros:

```
macro_rules! compose {
    ($($rest:ident),+) => {
        |x| { compose!(expand x, $($rest),*) }
    };
    (expand $inner:expr, $function:ident, $($rest:ident),*) => {
        compose!(expand $function($inner), $($rest),*)
    };
    (expand $inner:expr, $function:ident) => {
        $function($inner)
    };
}

let a = compose!(f, g, h, i);
//expands into:
let a = |x| i(h(g(f(x))));
```

Comment: Cool!! It works great! I also wonder if this code is the only way although I marked the answer as accepted. I mean another possibility to implement the recursive macros.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will study this code.